# How to map data using vue js in table form?

Tags: vue.js

This is the data format for showing the data in table format

```
transformedData=
    {
          missingReports: [
            {
              empId: "1234",
              empName: "Aarohi",
              monthTotalHours: {
                11-2022:{ allocation: 32, totalHoursMissing: 6, difference: 21 },
                12-2022:{ allocation: 91, totalHoursMissing: 3, difference: 45 }
              }
            },
            {
              empId: "2345",
              empName: "Aarush",
              monthTotalHours: {
               11-2022: {allocation:10, totalHoursMissing: 2, difference: 21 }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

This is how I want the output in table form

```
EmpId   EmpName  Nov2022al  Nov2022hr  Nov2022dif   Dec2022al  Dec2022hr  Dec2022dif
                                                                              


1234     Aarohi  32         6           21          91         3              45
2345     Aarush  10         2           21
```

This is what I have tried till now. Here getTableHeader is the month-year that we are getting after selecting from date picker.

```
<template v-for="employee in transformedData">
             <tr v-for="data in employee" :key="data.empId">
               <!-- <tr v-for="item in data" :key="item.empId"> -->
                 <!-- <template v-for="(item,index) in data"> -->
              <td class="td-empId">{{ data.empId }}</td>
              <td class="td-empName">{{ data.empName }}</td>
              <template
                v-for="(date, dIndex) in getTableHeader"
              >
                 <span v-for="(monthTotalHours, mIndex) in Object.values(data.monthTotalHours)" :key="mIndex">
                   <td :key="'TT' + dIndex">{{monthTotalHours.allocation | decimalFix}}</td>
                   <td :key="'DD' + dIndex">{{monthTotalHours.totalHoursMissing | decimalFix}}</td>
                   <td :key="'DDD' + dIndex">{{monthTotalHours.difference | decimalFix}}</td>
                 </span>
             </template>
           </tr>
    </template>
```

Comment: Mind providing the details of `transformedData`, and `getTableHeader`?

Comment: transformedData is the complete data I have provided at first and getTableHeader will convert mm-yyyy into this format Nov2022 that we are showing in the header that I have selected from date picker

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to make an array of all available headers which is dynamic since it can vary based on `monthTotalHours` data

You can use this code to make it easy to use

```js
const missingReports = [
  {
    empId: "1234",
    empName: "Aarohi",
    monthTotalHours: {
      "11-2022": { allocation: 32, totalHoursMissing: 6, difference: 21 },
      "12-2022": { allocation: 91, totalHoursMissing: 3, difference: 45 }
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "2345",
    empName: "Aarush",
    monthTotalHours: {
      "11-2022": { allocation: 10, totalHoursMissing: 2, difference: 21 }
    }
  }
];

const headers = ["empId", "empName"];
const months = [
  "Jan",
  "Feb",
  "Mar",
  "Apr",
  "May",
  "Jun",
  "Jul",
  "Aug",
  "Sep",
  "Oct",
  "Nov",
  "Dec"
];

const transformed_data = missingReports.map((report) => {
  // add columns to header;
  let rprt = {
    empId: report.empId,
    empName: report.empName
  };

  for (const date in report.monthTotalHours) {
    let [month, year] = date.split("-");
    let column_prefx = `${months[month - 1]}${year}`;
    let columns = [
      `${column_prefx}al`,
      `${column_prefx}hr`,
      `${column_prefx}dif`
    ];
    if (!headers.includes(columns[0])) {
      headers.push(...columns);
    }
    // add value with generated column name to the report
    const date_data = {
      [columns[0]]: report.monthTotalHours[date].allocation,
      [columns[1]]: report.monthTotalHours[date].totalHoursMissing,
      [columns[2]]: report.monthTotalHours[date].difference
    };
    rprt = { ...rprt, ...date_data };
  }

  return rprt;
});

console.log(transformed_data)
console.log(headers)
```

Now Since you have all the headers beforehand you can simply print those headers

Here comes the tricky part.

I transformed the data so that `monthTotalHours.date.allocation` will be available as `Nov2022hr` which will reflect the header name

So, What you will have to do is run 2 loop, One for the reports and in that loop run another loop for headers where you will get the header name

Then you can just print the data like this e.g `report[header name]`

Of course you will have to print the header name using a loop aswell.

e.g for the table printing

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="header in headers">
        {{header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="report in transformed_data">
      <td v-for="header in headers">
        {{report[header]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't have any other way in my mind, but what is wrong with this implementation? Do you have any limitations?

Comment: Actually, I'm using pagination to show the data and due to that the data is not coming properly the complete data is getting shifted

Comment: I see, so the table headers can change based on your paginated data, in that case, you can either retransform the data on every pagination or either get every possible header from the backend initially and then just push or change the table data any way you like

Comment: Even if I'm using your logic I'm getting data in this format but it should be in the order you have mentioned.
[
  {
    "Dec2022al": 91,
    "Dec2022hr": 3,
    "Dec2022dif": 45,
    "Nov2022al": 32,
    "Nov2022hr": 6,
    "Nov2022dif": 21,
    "empId": "1234",
    "empName": "Aarohi"
  },
  {
    "Nov2022al": 10,
    "Nov2022hr": 2,
    "Nov2022dif": 21,
    "empId": "2345",
    "empName": "Aarush"
  }
]